# How to fit ScrollView children to the size of the ScrollView in Nativescript-Vue?

Tags: vue.js, nativescript, scrollview, width, nativescript-vue

In Nativescript-Vue, if I have a ScrollView that is horizontal containing a GridLayout with some elements, let's say simple Labels, how do I make sure that each individual Label does not exceed the ScrollView's width? So that the user will see one full Label (or more, if the Label is short) in the ScrollView and text will never be cut off?

I've tried setting the width of Labels to 100% but it will not work, tried setting the GridLayout width, also does not work.

This is what I have

```
<template>
  <StackLayout height="100%" width="100%" backgroundColor="#add8e6">
    <ScrollView id="scroll" orientation="horizontal">
      <GridLayout class="m-15" rows="auto" backgroundColor="#90ee90"
                  columns="auto, auto">
        <Label class="h3 m-15" col="0" textWrap="true"
               text="Title bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 1"></Label>

        <Label class="h3 m-15" col="1"
               text="Title bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 2"></Label>
      </GridLayout>
    </ScrollView>
  </StackLayout>
</template>
```

Comment: May be I misunderstood, but why you even need a horizontal scroll when you do not want your labels to exceed the container's width?

Comment: Because I for instance want a scrollable bar with status messages or CardViews that contain some notifications or something, the user could then scroll through them and see each card in full on the view, and not see 50% of the card on his phone because it's too long.

Comment: Did you check nativescript-pager plugin?

Comment: Nice! Hadn't seen that one thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `FlexboxLayout` instead of `GridLayout`.

The `FlexboxLayout` will take all available space even if the content is short. If needed, scrollbars are added thanks to ScrollView.

You can then play with `justifyContent` and `alignItems` to control alignment, especially when content is short (for instance to center it on the page).

```html
<template>
  <Page backgroundColor="#add8e6">
    <ScrollView id="scroll" orientation="horizontal">
      <FlexboxLayout class="m-15" flexDirection="row" backgroundColor="#90ee90">
        <Label class="h3 m-15" textWrap="true"
               text="Title bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 1"></Label>

        <Label class="h3 m-15"
               text="Title bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla 2"></Label>
      </FlexboxLayout>
    </ScrollView>
  </Page>
</template>
```